# What is Wolverine the best at?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

One of the common lines associated with Wolverine is "He's the best he is at what he does."
Now I think the line sounds great and it truly gives you an image of Logan, but I've never quite understood if this is supposed to allude to something specific or if it's just a general "he'll get the job done phrase. So what exactly is it that Wolverine does?

Comment: The full quote is something like: **He's the best he is at what he does, and what he does isn't very nice.** Which is a not-so-subtle allusion to killing people.

Comment: “Being an asshole” fits quite nicely.

Comment: Geography bees.

Comment: Witty one-liners.  The second half alludes to the fact that they don't always make sense.

Comment: In any case, Deadpool's the best at whatever it is wolverine does.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Chris Claremont](http://www.mania.com/legends-chris-claremont_article_114549.html) started it all in the original four-part [Wolverine limited series](http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_Vol_1_1) from September to December of 1982 in which Wolverine's catchphrase, **"I'm the best there is at what I do, but what I do best isn't very nice,"** was debuted.

This catchphrase, which has been repeated over and over again throughout the years, alludes to maiming, killing or otherwise hurting people.  As internal monologue this, now popular, phrase had to do with Wolvie's negative perception of his identity.  Something Claremont (and writers after him) have tried to get *everyone's favorite hairy Canuck* to overcome.

[image]

While Wolverine is no longer the [mindless berserker](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/xmen96berserker1.jpg) he was when he was introduced into the pages of the X-Men he still uses the catchphrase. In fact in a recent article [Paul Montgomery](https://twitter.com/fuzzytypewriter) [Marvel.com] said that "Being the best he is at what he does has always required of Logan a dauntless abandon."

[image][image]
<sub>(source: [comichron.com](https://www.comichron.com/monthlycomicssales/monthlyimages/1988/198807Wolverine1.jpg))</sub>  [image]

Comment: Great answer. I assumed it meant that he was the best at killing but he's hardly ever shown as killing anyone anymore.

Answer (score -1):

From the animated series:

> Laser beams, I smell 'em

Given the implausibility of the feat, I'd say that he is probably better than anybody else at smelling out god damned lasers!

Comment: I believe the correct phrase is "frikking laser beams."  (Especially when said laser beams are mounted on sharks.)

Comment: Implausible? Lasers strong enough to cut flesh and bone, probably have high voltage drivers which have o3/ozone hazards (Just like laser printers do). He could just be efficiently smelling the very small ppm ozone creation. Ozone has a distinct smell.